# dynamically refering to different JLabels

Tags: java, string, arraylist, indexof

i have a bunch of `JLabel`, named conveniently like: `labelhely_0`, `labelhely_1` and so on.
they are stored in an `ArrayList` named helyek, in that order also.
i want to access them randomly,so i get the size of the arraylist, and use it to generate the number, in this case the desired "index" of the `JLabel` 
like this 
`int ujindex=helyek.indexOf("labelhely_"+indexx);`
Is there a way to cast the String in a way that it thinks that it's the name of the object?
i need this because i'm removing stuff from the ArrayList which messes up the indexing.

Comment: *"it thinks that it's the name of the object?"* - This isn't how java works. We'd need more context and information before we'd be able to recommend a solution, but you "might" consider using a `Map` of some kind

Comment: of course. a freakin Map. so sleep deprived can't think straight. thanks

Comment:  I know that feeling!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're saying does not work, your `ArrayList` contains JLabels and not String instances, therefore, `indexOf("labelhely_0")` would return -1 (meaning: not found). After all, the string `"labelhely_0"` is not in your list (a JLabel that has that text is, though).

There is no way to 'cast' a string to a JLabel: Casting is the act of asserting that a thing is another thing. (You may have learned that it converts things; that's not what casts do; that's only for primitives, and strings and jlabels aren't and cannot be made primitives).

Given that they are in the same order and you have indexx going, ujindex would be equal to indexx, so this entire operation sounds pointless to me.

Comment: yes, i'm aware of the fact that those are Jlabels and not Strings.
But can i get to the object via the String? in any way shape or form.
so if i have "labelhely_0" as an input, it would return the Jlabel for me?

Comment: Build a `Map<String, JLabel>` where the key is the 'input' and the value is the `JLabel`?

Comment: @user2478398 that MAY help, but it's hard to say as the original question doesn't really explain what's going on. Taking it literally, the correct code is literally `juindex = indexx;` – but I doubt that's really what OP wants.

Comment: A HashMap would do the job i guess, gonna use the indexes as the key and the JLabels as the value. i hope i can do that.

it's for a boardgame type of thing, i need to mess around with JLabels a lot.

Comment: @Pistee You can also loop through the entire list and call .getText() or whatever it is on each and every JLabel and compare _THAT_ instead. The Map solution is then probably better.